# how to sum data from different columns of two tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having two tables A, B.

```
Table A: Columns: UId, Price, FKIDTableB
Table B: Columns: IDTableB, amount, adminfee, discount
```

FKIDTableB is the foreignKy in table B.

I want to sum(Price) Column + amount +adminfee - discount where FKIDTableB = IDTable B

Comment: What is the cardinality between A and B?  one to one? one to many (a-<B?)  Many to one (A>-B)?  I have a concern without knowing this price could be inflated on a sum or the amounts could be inflated if not a 1-1 relationship.

Comment: Table B to table A ( 1 to many)

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two table like this:

```
select b.*,
    a.sum_of_price + b.amount + b.adminfee - b.discount
from tableb b
join (
    select FKIDTableB,
        sum(price) as sum_of_price
    from tablea
    group by FKIDTableB
    ) a on b.IDTableB = a.FKIDTableB
```

Comment: this query is giving the correct result but for all the records...but I need the result for only single record i.e. selected record...

Comment: @A.G - Use a where clause to select a particular record. If that is not what you are asking, please add sample data, expected output and clear explanation of what you want to do.